# Auto conversion between scala and java collections when using scala.collection.JavaConversions._ in scala 2.8

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

I have java API which return this type:

```
ArrayList[ArrayList[String]] = Foo.someJavaMethod()
```

In scala program, I need to send above type as a parameter to a scala function 'bar' whose type is

```
def bar(param: List[List[String]]) : List[String] = {

}
```

so I call bar like:

```
val list = bar(Foo.someJavaMethod())
```

but this does not work as I get compile error.

I thought have this import

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

will do implicit automatic conversion between Java and Scala collections.

I also tried using like:

```
Foo.someJavaMethod().toList
```

but that does not work either.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, `ArrayList` does not convert to `List`, it converts to a Scala `Buffer`. Second, implicit conversion will not recurse into the elements of your collections.

You'll have to manually map the inner lists. Either with implicit conversions:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
val f = Foo.someJavaMethod()
bar(f.toList.map(_.toList))
```

Or, more explicitly, if you prefer:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val f = Foo.someJavaMethod()
bar(f.asScala.toList.map(_.asScala.toList))
```